# When ALL Products Are Removed From Checkout - ReDirect to Shop Page

Tags: javascript, php, woocommerce

First of all, I have no idea how old and / or deprecated (that's the word right?) this code is. My old developer (passed away) gave it to me well over two years ago, and now I am trying to make sense of it all.

Not being a programmer, I need help with two things, whereof the second part is the most important. When ALL products are removed from the checkout, redirect to the shop page.

This is the code I am using for adding qty and what not to the checkout.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'jess_product_thumbnail_on_checkout_order_review', 20, 3 );
function jess_product_thumbnail_on_checkout_order_review( $product_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
if ( is_checkout() ) {
$product = $cart_item['data'];
$thumbnail = $product->get_image(array(50, 50));
$image_html = '<div class="product-item-thumbnail">' . $thumbnail . '</div>';
$product_name_link = '<a href="' . $product->get_permalink() . '">' . $product_name . '</a>';
$product_name = $image_html . $product_name_link;
}
return $product_name;
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'jess_product_image_css_checkout', 900 );
function jess_product_image_css_checkout(){
if (is_checkout()){ ?>
<style>
.product-item-thumbnail{float:left; padding-right:20px;}
.product-item-thumbnail img{margin:0!important;}
</style>
<?php
}}

add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity', 'jess_qty_change_remove_item_checkout_order_review', 1000, 3);
function jess_qty_change_remove_item_checkout_order_review( $quantity_html, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
$_product = $cart_item['data'];
if ($_product->is_sold_individually()){
$product_quantity = sprintf('<input type="hidden" name="cart[%s][qty]" value="" />', $cart_item_key);
}else{
$product_quantity = woocommerce_quantity_input(
array(
'input_name' => "cart[{$cart_item_key}][qty]",
'input_value' => $cart_item['quantity'],
'max_value' => $_product->get_max_purchase_quantity(),
'min_value' => '1',
'class' => 'qtyinput',
'placeholder' => 'Qty',
'product_name' => $_product->get_name(),
),
$_product,
false
);
}
$cart = WC()->cart->get_cart();
foreach ($cart as $cart_key => $cart_value){
if ($cart_key == $cart_item_key){
$product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
$_product = $cart_item['data'] ;
$remove_product = sprintf(
'<a href="%s" class="remove-product" title="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" data-cart_item_key="%s">Remove</a>',
esc_url(wc_get_cart_remove_url($cart_key)),
__( 'Remove From My Order', 'woocommerce' ),
esc_attr( $product_id ),
esc_attr( $_product->get_sku() ),
esc_attr( $cart_item_key )
);
}}
return '<br><span class="product-quantity">' . sprintf( 'Qty: %s', $cart_item['quantity'] ) . ' / ' . $remove_product . '</span>'.$product_quantity.'';
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'refresh_checkout_on_quantity_change' );
function refresh_checkout_on_quantity_change() {
if (is_checkout()){ ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php $admin_url = get_admin_url(); ?>
jQuery("form.checkout").on("change", "input.qty", function(){
var data = {
action: 'update_order_qty',
security: wc_checkout_params.update_order_review_nonce,
post_data: jQuery('form.checkout').serialize()
};
jQuery.post('<?php echo $admin_url; ?>' + 'admin-ajax.php', data, function(response){
jQuery('body').trigger('update_checkout');
});
});
</script>
<?php
}}
add_action( 'init', 'jess_load_ajax_checkout_qty_and_removal' );
function jess_load_ajax_checkout_qty_and_removal(){
if (!is_user_logged_in()){
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_update_order_qty', 'update_order_qty');
}else{
add_action( 'wp_ajax_update_order_qty', 'update_order_qty');
}}
function update_order_qty(){
$values = array();
parse_str($_POST['post_data'], $values);
$cart = $values['cart'];
foreach ($cart as $cart_key => $cart_value){
WC()->cart->set_quantity( $cart_key, $cart_value['qty'], false );
WC()->cart->calculate_totals();
woocommerce_cart_totals();
}
exit;
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'jess_remove_product_from_checkout_script' );
function jess_remove_product_from_checkout_script() { ?>
<script>
jQuery( function($){
if (typeof woocommerce_params === 'undefined')
return false;
console.log('defined');
$(document).on('click', 'tr.cart_item a.remove-product', function (e){
e.preventDefault();
var product_id = $(this).attr("data-product_id"),
cart_item_key = $(this).attr("data-cart_item_key"),
product_container = $(this).parents('.shop_table');
product_container.block({
message: null,
overlayCSS: {
cursor: 'none'
}
});
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'json',
url: wc_checkout_params.ajax_url,
data: {
action: "product_remove",
product_id: product_id,
cart_item_key: cart_item_key
},
success: function (result) {
$('body').trigger('update_checkout');
console.log(result);
}
});
});
});
</script>
<?php
}
add_action('wp_ajax_product_remove', 'ajax_product_remove');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_product_remove', 'ajax_product_remove');
function ajax_product_remove(){
ob_start();
foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item) {
if($cart_item['product_id'] == $_POST['product_id'] && $cart_item_key == $_POST['cart_item_key'] ) {
WC()->cart->remove_cart_item($cart_item_key);
}
}
WC()->cart->calculate_totals();
WC()->cart->maybe_set_cart_cookies();
woocommerce_order_review();
$woocommerce_order_review = ob_get_clean();
}
```

Comment: inside this function `jess_qty_change_remove_item_checkout_order_review`, after you declare `$cart = WC()->cart->get_cart();` simply check how many items are in cart: `if (count($cart) == 0) { /* CART IS EMPTY, REDIRECT HERE */ }`

Comment: That did not work. I still get this message: "Sorry, your session has expired. Return to shop".

Comment: Someone else said this: "wc_cart_emptied is ajax action that will be triggered when you remove all items from cart which you can use. Make sure the action is triggerd on checkout." But I do not know how for when all products are removed, so that the redirect to the shop happens.

Comment: The issue that you have is bcs when you remove product from the cart you are not updating the minicart which conflics and from there you get this message. After some tests you have to either rewrite all or like i said make sure you load cart scripts in your checkout. Then use the same classes from cart. For example in your code you are using class  remove-product instead change it to product-remove. Remove also  jess_remove_product_from_checkout_script function and hook with ajax_product_remove function and hooks.

Comment: Also keep in mind using any marketing plugins for discounts etc may not work with this approach since they are not intended to work on checkout when you update products qtys etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the modified code. I have added some comments where what is changed. This is tested on storefront theme and works.

```
//We need to load cart scripts
function checkout_woocommerce_scripts() 
{ 
  if ( is_checkout() ) wp_enqueue_script( 'wc-cart' ); 
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'checkout_woocommerce_scripts', 10 ); 

//When we remove all products from checkout will redirect to cart so we redirect to shop instead
//This also will work if we are on cart page and remove all products
add_action('template_redirect','redirect_cart_page');
function redirect_cart_page() {
    if(is_cart() && WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() == 0 ):
        wp_safe_redirect(wc_get_page_permalink( 'shop' ));
    endif;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'jess_product_thumbnail_on_checkout_order_review', 20, 3 );
function jess_product_thumbnail_on_checkout_order_review( $product_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    if ( is_checkout() ) {
        $product = $cart_item['data'];
        $thumbnail = $product->get_image(array(50, 50));
        $image_html = '<div class="product-item-thumbnail">' . $thumbnail . '</div>';
        $product_name_link = '<a href="' . $product->get_permalink() . '">' . $product_name . '</a>';
        $product_name = $image_html . $product_name_link;
    }
    return $product_name;
}

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'jess_product_image_css_checkout', 900 );
function jess_product_image_css_checkout(){
    if (is_checkout()){ ?>
        <style>
        .product-item-thumbnail{float:left; padding-right:20px;}
        .product-item-thumbnail img{margin:0!important;}
        </style>
    <?php
    }
}


//In this function all i did change is the class of the remove button from remove-product to product-remove
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity', 'jess_qty_change_remove_item_checkout_order_review', 1000, 3);
function jess_qty_change_remove_item_checkout_order_review( $quantity_html, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    $_product = $cart_item['data'];
    if ($_product->is_sold_individually()){
        $product_quantity = sprintf('<input type="hidden" name="cart[%s][qty]" value="" />', $cart_item_key);
    }else{
        $product_quantity = woocommerce_quantity_input(
            array(
                'input_name' => "cart[{$cart_item_key}][qty]",
                'input_value' => $cart_item['quantity'],
                'max_value' => $_product->get_max_purchase_quantity(),
                'min_value' => '1',
                'class' => 'qtyinput',
                'placeholder' => 'Qty',
                'product_name' => $_product->get_name(),
            ),
            $_product,
            false
        );
    }
    $cart = WC()->cart->get_cart();
    foreach ($cart as $cart_key => $cart_value){
        if ($cart_key == $cart_item_key){
            $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
            $_product = $cart_item['data'] ;
            $remove_product = sprintf(
            '<a href="%s" class="product-remove" title="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" data-cart_item_key="%s">Remove</a>',
            esc_url(wc_get_cart_remove_url($cart_key)),
            __( 'Remove From My Order', 'woocommerce' ),
            esc_attr( $product_id ),
            esc_attr( $_product->get_sku() ),
            esc_attr( $cart_item_key )
            );
        }
    }
    return '<br><span class="product-quantity">' . sprintf( 'Qty: %s', $cart_item['quantity'] ) . ' / ' . $remove_product . '</span>'.$product_quantity.'';
}


// I have added wc_fragment_refresh to update your minicart when qty change.
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'refresh_checkout_on_quantity_change' );
function refresh_checkout_on_quantity_change() {
if (is_checkout()){ ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <?php $admin_url = get_admin_url(); ?>
    jQuery("form.checkout").on("change", "input.qty", function(){
        var data = {
        action: 'update_order_qty',
        security: wc_checkout_params.update_order_review_nonce,
        post_data: jQuery('form.checkout').serialize()
        };
        jQuery.post('<?php echo $admin_url; ?>' + 'admin-ajax.php', data, function(response){   
            jQuery('body').trigger( 'wc_fragment_refresh' );
            jQuery('body').trigger('update_checkout');
        });
    });
    </script>
<?php

    }   
}
// You dont need to wrap this in a function and do checks wp_ajax_nopriv runs for guests where wp_ajax runs for users
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_update_order_qty', 'update_order_qty');
add_action( 'wp_ajax_update_order_qty', 'update_order_qty');

function update_order_qty(){
    $values = array();
    parse_str($_POST['post_data'], $values);
    $cart = $values['cart'];
    foreach ($cart as $cart_key => $cart_value){
        WC()->cart->set_quantity( $cart_key, $cart_value['qty'], false );
        WC()->cart->calculate_totals();
        woocommerce_cart_totals();
    }
    exit;
}
```

**This is i think the better solution when we want to update cart items in checkout. Its all woocommerce core so it will perform and last longer than custom code for people who are not into coding.**

Here is a video how its working https://webm.red/iV0t . It may get deleted after time.

```
//We need to load cart scripts
function checkout_woocommerce_scripts() 
{ 
  if ( is_checkout() ) wp_enqueue_script( 'wc-cart' ); 
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'checkout_woocommerce_scripts', 10 ); 

//If we want to redirect to shop page when cart or checkout get empty.
add_action('template_redirect','redirect_cart_page');
function redirect_cart_page() {
    if(is_cart() && WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() == 0 ):
        wp_safe_redirect(wc_get_page_permalink( 'shop' ));
    endif;
}

//Load the cart form provided by woocommerce as shortcode.
// I will keep it outside the checkout form since its a form on its self.
// If we want we can extend the layout with modifying the checkout template.
add_action('woocommerce_before_checkout_form','checkout_cart_form');
function checkout_cart_form() {
    echo do_shortcode('[woocommerce_cart]');
}

//Since we load cart form we dont need the coupon form twice

//Remove checkout coupon form comment this if you want to use this instead
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'woocommerce_checkout_coupon_form', 10 ); 

//Remove cart coupon form
function hide_coupon_field_on_cart( $enabled ) { 
    if ( is_cart() ) { $enabled = false; } return $enabled; 
} 

//Uncomment this if you want to use this coupon form 
// add_filter( 'woocommerce_coupons_enabled', 'hide_coupon_field_on_cart' );


//The scripts and styles we gonna use. Feel free to move them in your theme css js files (make sure they are loaded on checkout page)
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'checkout_styles_scripts');
function checkout_styles_scripts() {
?>
<style>
body.woocommerce-checkout button[name="update_cart"],
body.woocommerce-checkout input[name="update_cart"] {
    display: none;
}
</style>
<script>
jQuery( function( $ ) {
    let timeout;
    $('.woocommerce').on( 'change keyup mouseup', 'input.qty', function(){
        if ( timeout !== undefined ) {
            clearTimeout( timeout );
        }
        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            $("[name='update_cart']").trigger("click"); // trigger cart update
        }, 1000 ); // 1 second delay, half a second (500) seems comfortable too
    });
} );
</script>
<?php
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Very kind of you taking the time to make this work. Thank you.